# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'WebElement' and 'WebElement'

Tags: python, selenium

It is giving me this error and I am not sure why.

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='error']") & driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']"):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'WebElement' and 'WebElement'
```

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("center").click()

if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='error']") & \

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']"):

driver.refresh()

else:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()
```

Also in my script even though python is showing the last code is correct but isn't executing this line.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()
```

I mean this last `xpath` works fine when I write this code separately but when I used it in an `if` statement and write it after `else` it doesn't work.

I am not sure where I am making mistakes.

Comment: & is pretty explanatory with 2 web elements on either side.

Comment: Not supported for that type.

Answer (score 2):

Its expecting Boolean return value  Out of the conditions and Getting Web Element as Return value.

Use code below

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("center").click()
El1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='error']")
El2= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']")
if (El1!=null)&\(El2!=null):
driver.refresh()
else:     
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()
```

Comment: When i post your script it gives me error at these signs &\ and !=  And also in the last expath it says 120/150 words longer not sure what it means